# What difference between ('xyz' != 'xyz') and NOT ('xyz' = 'xyz')

Tags: oracle, performance, optimization, query-optimization

Is there any difference between `('xyz' != 'xyz')` and `NOT ('xyz' = 'xyz')`

Though I am asking in context of Oracle DB, but would also like to know for same situation in other languages too.

Differences mainly like *processing speed* and all that background stuff.

Comment: As you can see, from Lalit's answer, the answer obviously is "No" because your literal values are identical. I suspect you actually meant the more general case, e.g. `(:bind1 != :bind1)` vs `NOT (:bind1 = :bind1)` - am I right?

Comment: Yes actually, I meant for more general case indeed. And also the comparison in contrast to some other languages too.

Comment: The answer is the same: if :bind is not null, the result of both expressions is TRUE. If :bind is null, the result of both expressions is UNKNOWN.

Comment: My answer was specific to the question, and very specific to the literals involved. On whole, it is a too broad question, and thus in general my answer would suffice OP's need. Anyway, I would expect it to be marked as answered if it answers in the scope of the question.

Comment: For the question, ok your answer suffice the explanation, but as you had also said, I would also be liking it to be thought in broad sense. Thanks

Comment: @sachin, sure. Please feel welcomed to post another question with more specifics on the database. I would love to participate/answer. My expertise is somewhat confined to Oracle database. I have upvoted your question for a reason :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see any difference?

**Test Case:**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM dual
  2  WHERE ('xyz' != 'xyz');

no rows selected

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM dual
  2  WHERE NOT ('xyz' = 'xyz');

no rows selected
```

In both the above queries, the filter applied is same **filter(NULL IS NOT NULL)**.

**Execution plan:**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT * FROM dual
  3  WHERE ('xyz' != 'xyz');

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3752461848

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |     2 |     0   (0)|          |
|*  1 |  FILTER            |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL)

14 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT * FROM dual
  3  WHERE NOT ('xyz' = 'xyz');

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3752461848

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |     2 |     0   (0)|          |
|*  1 |  FILTER            |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL)

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

No difference.

Comment: Hmmm... you seem to be assuming the OP was asking about the literal value `'xyz'`, which doesn't make much sense (obviously `'xyz'` equals `'xyz'`). In your case, the optimiser is able to eliminate the predicate completely but that's just because the expression only has literal values. Admittedly, the question is poorly worded.

Comment: I completely agree with you. OP has worded the question too generally. It wouldn't have been much difficult to just show that `1=1` is always true ;-) I wish if the question would have been specific about **NOT**, in a more specific use case. This is the reason I added explain plan.

Comment: This is why I tend to ask clarifying questions before jumping ahead with an  answer :)

Comment: Hmm...sometimes not all days are same ;-) On few days, my fingers are ahead of my thoughts.